# object referenced by one iterator been erased by other

Tags: c++, iterator, stdlist

I have a list of `std::function`.

When iterating the list, the function would be called, and in some case it would be removed in the function call. In this case, crash occurs when incrementing iterator in the for loop because the iterator points to a not existing element.

Here is my code:

```
for (std::list<MessageCallback>::iterator it = _msg_callbacks.begin(); it != _msg_callbacks.end(); ++it) {
    if (-1 == it->msg_type || msg_type == it->_msg_type) {
        if (-1 == it->msg_id || response_msg_id == it->_msg_id) {
            it->_msg_handler(msg_type, msg_id, data);
        }
    }
}
```

the user defined msg_handler are likely to call remove_callback in which the callback would be erased by other iterator.

currently the workaround is adding it++ and it-- around msg_handler call.

here is the code

```
for (std::list<MessageCallback>::iterator it = _msg_callbacks.begin(); it != _msg_callbacks.end(); ++it) {
    if (-1 == it->msg_type || msg_type == it->_msg_type) {
        if (-1 == it->msg_id || response_msg_id == it->_msg_id) {
             std::function<...> handle = it->_msg_handler(msg_type, msg_id, data);
             it++;
             handle(msg_type, msg_id, data);
             it--;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where is your `msg_type` and `msg_id`?

Comment: @appleapple msg_type and msg_id passing as function parameters

Comment: (not the answer) but than I think you should not check `-1 == msg_type` inside loop

Comment: @appleapple -1 is for passing the check, yes i should use -1 == it->msg_type

Answer (score 1):

You can use `erase` and continue your loop using its return value:

```
for (std::list<MessageCallback>::iterator it = _msg_callbacks.begin(); it != _msg_callbacks.end(); ++it) {
    if (-1 == msg_type || msg_type == it->_msg_type) {
        if (-1 == msg_id || response_msg_id == it->_msg_id) {
            it->_msg_handler(msg_type, msg_id, data);
        }
    }
    
    // some case to remove the function
    
    it = _msg_callbacks.erase(it);
}
```

From cppreference.com on [std::list::erase](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/erase):

> **Return value**
>
> Iterator following the last removed element. If the iterator pos refers to the last element, the [end()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/end) iterator is returned.

**EDIT:**

On second reading on your question, it looks like your callback is actually removing the function. So what you can do is making it return the post-erase iterator:

```
std::list<MessageCallback>::iterator foo_callback(
    /* decltype */ msg_type,
    /* decltype */ msg_id,
    /* decltype */ data
)
{
    // ...
    // eventually extract iterator it from data; otherwise, you should pass it as argument

    return _msg_callbacks.erase(it);
}
```

Then take it back in your loop:

```
for (std::list<MessageCallback>::iterator it = _msg_callbacks.begin(); it != _msg_callbacks.end(); ++it) {
    if (-1 == msg_type || msg_type == it->_msg_type) {
        if (-1 == msg_id || response_msg_id == it->_msg_id) {
            it = it->_msg_handler(msg_type, msg_id, data);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for you reply, but it's hard to make users return an iterator in their defined callback since the list of all callbacks should be transparent to them

Answer (score 1):

`list::erase()` invalidates all iterators, references, or pointers to the erased element(s), and return an iterator to the element that followed the last erased element.    If there is no following element, the end iterator is returned.

Your loop is not taking that into account.

You therefore need to find a way of returning the iterator returned by `erase()` so it can be used in your loop.   Alternatively (assuming your callback is only erasing the iterator passed) your loop can use another `iterator` (say, `next_it`), assign `next_it = it + 1` before calling the callback function, and then set `it = next_it` instead of performing `++it`.

Comment: thanks for your explain! your second method is better than my workaround